# how can i configure adobe flex to run my application with parameters and how do i retrieve them?

Tags: apache-flex

I want my flex application to receive a string parameter of the swf file it needs to load. is there a way to configure adobe flex 3 to run the application with parameters? how do I retrieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For runtime optional parameters you need to take a look into [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html)

For compile time parameters take a look into [conditional compilation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html)